# Use Route Handler both in React and Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am trying to show a component when someone goes to `/videocall` on the **React side** of my application.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path="/videocall" component={VideoCall} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

and here's how someone can go to that route through a button click from a **different component**.

```
<Link to='/videocall'>
  Go to Video Call
</Link>
```

And up until here it's working fine. I can see my new `VideoCall` component.

But I also want this route handler on the **Node/Express** side of my application so I can start a **Socket.io** server.

Since React and Express rendering are different so express doesn't know how to handle `/videocall`.

I am using it like below.

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

module.exports = (app, server) => {
  app.get('/api/videocall', (req, res) => {
    const io = socketIO(server);
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log('User connected');

      socket.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
      });

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User disconnected');
      });
    });
  });
}
```

And I am using a wildcard route match that will render the default `index.html` file like so:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

And it's working fine. When I go to `/videocall` from the *URL* I get routed to my **VideoCall** component.

But the client is only getting connected to the socket server when I go to `/api/videocall` and not when I go to `/videocall`.

How do I resolve that since I want the client to get connected to the socket server when he goes to `VideoCall` component from a different component on the front end like so:

```
<Link to='/videocall'>
  Go to Video Call
</Link>
```

Comment: This can be possible if you run your express server and react server on different subdomains

Comment: If express and react is hosted on same domain
And one route in defined in both
Then only express route will be accessable

Comment: One workaround can be to add a prefix to express routes /api/videocall

Comment: I also have to edit `Route path` on `BrowserRouter` too right?

Comment: No , You need to add a redirect route in express to navigate to react's index.html at the end

Comment: Yea its working but now the `console.log` statement is not coming when I go to that component through `<Link to='/videocall'>Go to Video Call</Link>`

Comment: I hosted them on the same domain. My request still hangs.

Comment: you need to add app.get('*',(req,res) => {res.sendFile(react index html);}); At the end of all api routes

Comment: It's working now but there's another issue. Can you check the question now

Comment: Since Your issue is resoldlved you should have upvoted by comment . As gratitude

Comment: Yea man. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally managed to make it work.

Here's how I did it.

I wrote my socket code in my `index.js` file and not in any route handler.

```
const socket = require('socket.io');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = app.listen(PORT);

const io = socket(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('User connected');

  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User disconnected');
  });
});
```

And in my VideoCall component I wrote my connect method inside `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. So now I am only connecting when I go that `/videocall` route.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
var socket;

class VideoCall extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
  }
}
```